# Adding to the front of link listing

Tags: c++

I am able to successfully add a name to the end of the list, but I am not able to add it to the front.
I am trying to figure out how to add to the front of the node, thank you.
I thought I understood that to add to the back, you use last ass the variable the code will cout, so I tried to manipulate that and use head to start at the beginning.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string name;
    string name1;
    node *next;

};

bool isEmpty(node *head);
char menu();
void insert(node *&head, node *&last, string name);
void insert_front(node *&head, node*&start, string name1);
void insert_back(node *&head, node *&last, string name);

void print(node *current);
bool isEmpty(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


char menu()
{
    char choice;
    cout << "Menu\n";
    cout << "1. Add a name to the front of the list." << endl;
    cout << "2. Add a name to the back of the list." << endl;
    cout << "3. Print the list." << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

void insert(node *&head, node *&last, string name)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->name = name;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    last = temp;
}

void insert_back(node *&head, node *&last, string name)
{
    if (isEmpty(head))
        insert(head, last, name);
    else
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->name = name;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}

void insert_front(node *&head, node *& start, string name1)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->name1 = name1;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
void print(node *current)
{
    if (isEmpty(current))
        cout << "The list is emtpy." << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "List of names: \n";
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            cout << current->name << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node *last = NULL;
    node *start = NULL;
    char choice;
    string name, name1;
    do
    {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case '1':
            cout << "Enter first name to the front of the list: " << endl;
            cin >> name1;
            insert_front(head, start, name1);
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "Enter first name to the end of the list:" << endl;
            cin >> name;
            insert_back(head, last, name);
            break;
        case '3': print(head);
            break;
        case '4':
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 4);

}
```

Comment: Hint: insert_back() should be just like insert_front(). Except for the front/back thing. For example, insert_front() does something special in the case of an empty list. insert_back() should, obviously, do the same because if the list is empty, insert_front() and insert_back() is the same thing. The fact that your insert_back() does not do this should be your first honking clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: Your `print` function prints `current->name` but your `insert_front` method only sets `name1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of irrelevant "stuff" mixed in with the code to insert at the head of the list. Your `insert_front` isn't obviously wrong; if there's a problem, it's most likely elsewhere.

I'd narrow the code down to something simpler, with most other concerns removed. I'd also use the `ctor` to initialize a node properly, to get code something on this order:

```
#include <iostream>

class linked_list {

    struct node {
        int value;
        node *next;

        node(int value, node *next) : value(value), next(next) {}

        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, node const &n) {
            return os << n.value;
        }
    } *head = nullptr;

public:

    void add_front(int i) {
        head = new node(i, head);
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, linked_list const &ll) {
        for (node *n = ll.head; n != nullptr; n = n->next)
            os << *n << ' ';
        return os;
    }

};

int main() {
    linked_list data;

    data.add_front(1);
    data.add_front(2);
    data.add_front(5);
    std::cout << data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have chopped up your code into a minimal working set, please study and rewrite where necessary.  do be careful about lists, noticing that when you wish to change a head or tail value defined in main, you have to pass the address of the variable which itself is a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string name;
    node* next;
};

char menu() {
    char choice;
    cout << "Menu\n";
    cout << "1. Add a name to the front of the list." << endl;
    cout << "3. Print the list." << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

bool isEmpty(node* current) {
    return current == NULL;
}

void insert_front(node** head, string name) {
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->name = name;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
}

void print(node* root) {
    if (isEmpty(root))
        cout << "The list is emtpy." << endl;
    else {
        cout << "List of names: \n";
        node* current = root;
        while (current != NULL) {
            cout << current->name << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    node* head = NULL;
    node* last = NULL;
    char choice;
    string name;

    do {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            cout << "Enter first name to the front of the list: " << endl;
            cin >> name;
            insert_front(&head, name);
            break;
        case '3': print(head);
            break;
        case '4':
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
}
```